# System.InvalidOperationException: Startup assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy failed to execute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2022

```
---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(ObjectHandleOnStack assemblyName, ObjectHandleOnStack requestingAssembly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, ObjectHandleOnStack assemblyLoadContext, ObjectHandleOnStack retAssembly)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyName, RuntimeAssembly requestingAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, AssemblyLoadContext assemblyLoadContext)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.ExecuteHostingStartups()
```

I am somehow unable to start my app anymore and always get this error and results in a 404 on localhost.I dont know how i will be able to fix this and get my app running again. Hope somebody can help me thx.

Comment: can you add your csproj and startup.cs/program.cs files?

Comment: Hi @SyedMohammadFahimAbrar I was able to start my project somewhat  because under my cs.projekt properties the target framwork was not the same as the one in the cs file. When I changed that i could start the app again now it just gives me an ssl certificate error. But anyway thanks for your help

Answer (score 16):

I have this same problem in my AspNet React App.
The problem occurred due to me having updated the version of Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy to 7.0.0 while my project is using .NET 6

So, I downgrade the version of Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy to 6.0.11 and it works.

Comment: It was the other way round for me - but thanks, your post pointed me the right way. I really wished we would get more meaningful error messages.